# Using -notmatch with multiple filters

Tags: powershell

Using the search to find an answer is great except if you don't understand something in the answer:

SO doesn't allow you to ask for clarification so you have to post another thread; not very helpful to those looking for answers IMO.

But, found this in a thread related to my problem and it does seem to work. But, I can't figure out two things:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem $parentPath -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | ?{ $_.fullname -notmatch "\\obj\\?" }
```

1: Why do you have to use "\xxxx\?" and 
2: Is there a way of having an array or list of things to -notmatch on?

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

The -match and -notmatch operators will only accept a single regex argument, but you can use alternation in the regex to match multiple conditions in the same operation:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem $parentPath -Recurse -Exclude $exclude |
 ?{ $_.fullname -notmatch "\\(?:obj|bin)\\?" }
```

Comment: +1, with array you could extend your option: $alterarray=$array -join '|'; and use it as alternation

Comment: You can do that too, but it's best to run those through [regex]::escape() first or there may be some unintended consequences.

Comment: So the short answer is that the parameter -match and -notmatch, as you said, must be a regular expression? That's tough as my list to exclude is very long:

    $ExcludeDirs = ("Temporary ASP.NET Files","Temporary Internet Files","Temp","*$RECYCLE.BIN*","*System Volume Information*","RECYCLER")

So what's the best way to go about that? I was trying to use:

    $ExcludeDirs = ("Temporary ASP.NET Files","Temporary Internet Files","Temp","*$RECYCLE.BIN*","*System Volume Information*","RECYCLER")


But that was failing for some reason. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1)   explanation:

```
   \\ litteral character '\'
   \  author missed another '\' to escape
   \? Litteral character ?
```

Or

```
  \\ litteral character '\'
   \\ litteral character '\' 
    ? The last character is optional ( wrong because the last char is a special char and must be escaped)
```

The pattern must be `\\obj\\\? If you want match litteral '?' Or \\obj(?:\\)?` if you want use literral \ optionaly